# How to serialize and export data in ruby 2.2.4 (Windows)?

Tags: ruby, serialization, export

I need to export a Int converted string into binary data, so i can use it in a micro-controller.

Here is part of the code:

```
def save_hex

 text_hex = File.new("hex_#{@file_to_translate}.txt", "a+")

 @text_agreschar.each_with_index do |string_agreschar, index|
  string_hex = ''
  string_agreschar.each do |char_agreschar|
    string_hex << char_agreschar.agres_code.to_i
  end
  text_hex.print(string_hex)
  text_hex.puts('')
 end
end
```

I need to export my "string_hex" into a binary file, not a text.

PS I'm developing in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are looking for, but I believe that you want to do something like the following:

```rb
def save_hex

  text_hex = File.new("hex_#{@file_to_translate}.txt", "a+")

  @text_agreschar.each do |string_agreschar|
    string_hex = [] # create empty array instead of string
    string_agreschar.each do |char_agreschar|
      string_hex << char_agreschar.agres_code.to_i
    end
    text_hex.puts(string_hex.pack('L*')) # convert to "binary" string
  end
end
```

The array method `pack('L*')` will convert each (4 byte) integers in the `string_hex` array into a single string that represents the integers in binary format.

In case you need 8 byte integers you can use `pack('Q*')`. Check [this link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Array.html#method-i-pack) for other available formats.

Here is an example of using `Array#pack`:

```rb
i = 1234567

p(i.to_s(16))
#=> "12d687"

p([i].pack('L*'))
#=> "@\xE2\x01\x00"

p([i].pack('L>*')) # force big-endian
#=> "\x00\x12\xD6\x87"

p([i].pack('L>*').unpack('C*')) # reverse the operation to read bytes
#=> [0, 18, 214, 135]
```

Comment: Thank you so much...Problem solved! That was exactly what i was looking for.